# Static shocking my case causes USB to fail for a bit. Should I be worried?

Tags: power-supply, static-discharge

It's that time of year again where I frequently find myself stocking things with static electricity. The only grounded object around my desk that I can use to discharge myself is my computer case.

However, shocking the case frequently causes my USB keyboard and mouse to stop working for a few seconds.

My understanding is that the power supply should connect the case to the ground pin of the wall outlet, harmlessly dissipating any static shocks to it. So it's a bit worrying that my stocks are doing something.

Should I be worried? How can I either fix this issue, or diagnose it further to see what part of the computer (or even the outlet) is the issue?

Comment: Well, probably is the answer. Giving more electricity to your computer than it can handle is never a good idea, and I'd say you've been lucky so far that the effects are only temporary. If you keep it up, you run a heavy risk of frying your motherboard or any other components inside. Find something else to ground yourself, get an anti-static bracelet, anything else aside from your PC case.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I did some looking for anti-static wrist straps. The only ones I've found have an alligator clip with the instructions "attach to a metal part of your PC case" which is unhelpful. I've been unable to find any that connect to an outlet ground. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, having only used other methods of anti-static (grounding myself before entering a clean room for work), I can't be much more help. From what I can tell, however, grounding to your PC case actually makes it so you and your PC match in voltage, removing any chance of static buildup.